# I'm using id as identifier to find element, but exception stack trace is showing css selector

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium Web driver with Java code. Whenever org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException occurs, stack trace prints identifier method as `css selector` every time although I have used `id` to find web element.

I tried using `xpath` identifier and it prints perfect stack trace with correct identifier method. My sample code.

```
public void testMethod()
{
    try
    {
        driver.findElement(By.id("test"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Stack trace output:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#test"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'DTB150', ip: '10.37.55.150', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 75.0.3770.100, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 75.0.3770.90 (a6dcaf7e3ec6f..., userDataDir: C:\Users\DEV~1.SOL\AppData\...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:38152}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: b6c8f6cd722e746281dd59657850e10f
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=test}
```

Check method in first line of exception. It says `method: css selector` although I'm using `id` to find element.

Is that some kind of error or I have misunderstood something or some problem with my code?

Comment: Maybe under the hood Selenium is converting your "by Id" search strategy to the CSS selector strategy?

Answer (score 0):

See the **exception** : `Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#test"}`

in css selector `#` represent an id.

If **id** is **test** and you are using it like this :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("test"));
```

Exception should be related to id if not found.

But if you are using it like

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#test"));
```

You would get the same exception as mentioned above in OP.